Delphi 11, multi-line tabbed Palette possible?
I have downloaded and made first steps with modern Delphi 11 (community edition).
Compared to D6 / D7, I miss the possibility to have the palette be tabbed and multiline.
CNPack offers this option, but it's grayed out. Documentation does not give any details about this feature not being available anymore.
Is it possible to do at all ?



Which answer do you expect? As if pressing a secret combination of keys would enable it... Most likely Delphi's GUI is not native Windows anymore, and as such doesn't support everything from the past.

Delphi's GUI is still a native Windows app. It simply underwent a major redesign in Delphi 8.

@AmigoJack no, did not expect a "secret combination of keys". I had not viewed the source of CNPack, and wondered if there was some other setting. Again, quite new to D11 and all it's settings.

The two CnPack options you describe are disabled intentionally. Looking at the source code for that Settings window, they are both disabled in Delphi 8 and later:
{$IFDEF COMPILER8_UP}
  // 8 以及以上版本无此设置
  chkMultiLine.Enabled := False;
  chkButtonStyle.Enabled := False;
  chkDivTabMenu.Enabled := False;
{$ELSE}
  chkMultiLine.Enabled := True;
  chkButtonStyle.Enabled := True;
  chkDivTabMenu.Enabled := True;
{$ENDIF}

Which makes sense, as the IDE UI underwent a major redesign in Delphi 8. A tabbed Palette simply isn't available anymore in modern Delphi. The Palette is now available only as a context-sensitive panel that is dockable alongside the code editor.  It is no longer available as an embedded PageControl in the main toolbar.

The main reason why Embarcadero ditched the tabbed pallete design is that with tabbed palete design if you have many third party components installed you quickly run out of space to show all those additional tabs. So you end up with tabbed palete that you need to scroll left and right which becomes tiresome quite quickly. With current design scrolling up and down is a lot easier as you just use mouse wheel instead of clicking on button as you would need to do with tabbed pallete.. And aditionally it has ability to search for components so finding them by name is a lot faster.

"with tabbed palete design if you have many third party components installed you quickly run out of space to show all those additional tabs" - Hence the multi-line option. But yes, using a tabbed design was not the best option, even with just the stock components using lots of tabs already.
